# Даже несмотря на это, его продвижение было ужасно медленным

Tags: пунктуация

Стоит ли ставить запятую?
Даже несмотря на это(,) его продвижение было ужасно медленным.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Стоит ли ставить запятую?* Ее **надо** ставить.

**Даже несмотря на это, его продвижение было ужасно медленным.**

[НЕСМОТРЯ НА (что)](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_482), *предлог*
Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «несмотря на», обычно обособляются.
*Несмотря на солнечное, теплое утро, он был в шубе и, видимо, грелся на солнце* (Д. Мамин-Сибиряк. Волшебник).

Частица [даже](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_148) употреблена для усиления.

*Даже несмотря на это, мы видим, что есть существенная экономия на налоге* (из интервью); *И теперь, даже несмотря на седину, морщины и очки, иногда его худощавое лицо, особенно в профиль, кажется прекрасным* (Чехов).

Оборот с "несмотря на" не обособляется, если он входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу. Сравните:
Несмотря на запрет врачей, я написал в Малеевке повесть «Колхиду» (Паустовский).
Он сделал это несмотря на запреты врачей.